# Open Winform based on result from SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access-97

I am currently in the process of transferring an Access97 Database Application to a new WinForms application.

We have a central form for all "Accounts" which shows the general account data, within that form there is a button that opens another form, the application gets the form name from a SQL query using an example of the table below.

```
| ClientID | FormName |
+----------+----------+
|    1     |   frm1   |
|    2     |   frm2   |
```

So if the ClientID is 1 then the button should open Form1 if the ClientID is 2 the button should open Form2.

My question is how would I get WinForms to run the query on the button click to then open the corresponding form found within the table?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: we are not here to do the work  of the others post what u have tried and we will help u

Comment: I understand that, but the reason I am asking, is because I can't even begin to think where to begin. At present for testing I have the functionality of a simple button.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen With over 40 forms that can possible be opened, I thought there would be a better option.

Comment: @JammD You can name the forms accordingly and use reflection to create an instance based on the name in that case.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thank you, I now have a starting step to at least get the functionality I need.

Comment: @JammoD Not do distract from you getting your question answered is it possible to re engineer the solution to reduce the number of forms? Just something to think about.

Comment: @Bmo I can't see another solution around the problem, as each of the clients screens have particular needs and requirements, which need a different set of fields for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write an SQL helper method. Something like the following (which I have not checked and hacked up)

```
public static T SQLGet<T>(SqlConnection conn, string sql)
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = conn;
        command.CommandTimeout = 0; // No timeout - set or remove.
        command.CommandText = sql;
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(Command.ExecuteScalar(), typeof(T));
    }
}
```

you can use this like

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(someValidConnectionString);
string formName = Utilities.SQLGet<string>(conn, 
    "SELECT [FormName] " + 
    "FROM [SomeTable] WHERE [ClientID] = 1;") // Not considering SQL injection here!
```

Now you can use reflection with the retrieved name `formName`

```
Type t = assembly.GetType(formName);
Form frm1 = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

I hope this helps.

*Note. this does not have error handling.*

Comment: Using `as Form` instead of direct casting would help to reduce one exception and just allow comparing to null.